# Drive showing up as wrong model and brand

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have a five year old Lenovo T420 laptop and last week fitted a Seagate FireCuda 2.5in 1TB SSHD model (i.e. traditional HD with SSD cache), and a Sandisk mSata 32GB SSD cache card (cheap eBay clone? - it had Chinese holograms on it).

My C drive now shows up in Control Panel->Computer Management->Device Manager as WDC WD3200BEKX-60B7WTO.

I'm not complaining about speed - whatever it is it's quick, but why is it being detected wrongly, as not Seagate?

The drive I installed had Seagate labels and looks genuine.

OS is Windows 10.0.16299.64.

Comment: I think you need to talk to Seagate.

Comment: The WD3200BEKX is a 320gb drive: https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&q=WD3200BEKX Sounds like one way or another you need to talk to your supplier.

Comment: It shows up as 1TB on the device manager.Disk Management pane.

Comment: It had a 320GB Seagate Momentus in this before the upgrade.  The install is cloned from the old one with Aomei free edition.

Comment: The supplier is Amazon Prime.

Comment: delete the drive in device manager, reboot and let Windows install it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more time researching this, it seems that the device name displayed in Drive Management and the Device tree is cosmetic,

[Device Management mmc snap-in hard drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RNIt.png)

and taken from a registry key named “FriendlyName”

[FriendlyName registry image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu4Yq.png)

Simply right clicking Disk Drives->Scan for hardware changes results in this:

[refreshed hardware changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27IOw.png)

and it persists across reboots.

It was populated with the type of the drive of the Refurbisher ‘s OEM pre-installation image.   <s>There is even a PowerShell command `Set-PhysicalDisk` to change it.</s> (Corrected thanks to comment from @Kitet).

Investigation of other values in the same key reveals that it has got the correct vendor/device ID for the Seagate drive.

[Hardware ID in registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKKtY.png)

Also, Seagate diagnostic tools all show that it really is what it is supposed to be, and is working perfectly correctly.

[Seatools diagnostic utility shows correct drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAytf.png)

Whilst it seems that uninstalling the device to let Windows rediscover it is a valid option for some, in my case there is also a extra device driver installed to it, `excsd.sys` (ExpressCache),

[extra driver details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk5E9.png)

which is for synchronisation with the 32GB SanDisk SSD mSATA cache installed.  No doubt that unless I uninstall the external SSD cache first this could cause problems.  I would have to reinstall ReadyCache / ExpressCache and repopulate the cache from scratch.  I’ve edited the registry FriendlyName instead to avoid that.

This observation also permits benchmark fraud... see this:

[Benchmark fraud of fake hard drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaikG.png)

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The partion name is "Windows".  It's not that.

Comment: Will post extract from registry when I get back.

Comment: @Kitet - Images are here for you now.

Comment: SQL injection through the name of your drive to www.userbenchmark,com?

Comment: **"Uninstalling the device to let Windows rediscover it" worked** for me on a brand new disk (Western Digital HDD showing up as Samsung SSD). _Steps: Device Manager (devmgmt.msc) > Disk drives > right click on the correct disk (check Properties to confirm) > Uninstall device > restart Windows_

Answer (score -1):

We don’t need to care what this SSHD can be detected, just care the speed and stability.

SSHD is more like a faster HDD rather than SSD, so I guess system consider the HDD part as the whole SSHD, WDC WD3200BEKX-60B7WTO should be the HDD part’s model

You could contact Seagate for a explanation, but it doesn’t influence the use.

Comment: It could if the drive is running firmware not intended for use with it.

Comment: it does have this installed too: 

https://www.condusiv.com/partners/oem/technologies/expresscache/

from here:

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/downloads/ds104444

Comment: This shows up on the events tab of the properties box in device manager: 

Device SCSI\Disk&Ven_&Prod_ST1000LX015-1U71\4&1ef2f96b&0&000000 was migrated.

Last Device Instance Id: SCSI\Disk&Ven_WDC&Prod_WD3200BEKX-60B7W\4&1ef2f96b&0&000000
Class Guid: {4D36E967-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Location Path: ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(SAT1)#ACPI(PRT0)
Migration Rank: 0xF000FC0000000020
Present: false